# Вывод более глубоких элементов в ArrayList

Tags: java

Как получить(либо вывести в консоль) более глубокое значение ArrayList, например значение testVal из ArrayList-a parserJson, если он всегда имеет динамическую вложенность. Немного запутался во вложенности(скинул всё в один метод для упрощения восприятия). Заранее спасибо за любую помощь!

```
public void showList(ArrayList<JSONValue> parserJson) {
    boolean inQuotes = false;
    JSONValue testVal = new JSONValue(true);
    JSONObjectElement element = new JSONObjectElement("test", testVal);
    parserJson.add(new JSONValue(inQuotes));
    parserJson.add(new JSONValue(new JSONObject(element)));

    for (int index = 0; index < parserJson.size(); index++) {
        System.out.println(parserJson.get(index).getValues());
    }
}
```

Метод возвращающий значение:

```
public String getValues() {
    return value;
}
```

Comment: что значит вывести? куда вывести? и чем вас не устраивает ваш код?

Comment: Вывести в консоль в виде строки или получить. вот что выводится в консоль - com.package.JSONElements.JSONObject@15db9742.

Comment: вложенность может быть разной? название ключе заранее известны?

Comment: Может. Неизвестны.

Comment: попробуйте более четко сформулировать ваш вопрос. сейчас он совершенно непонятен. у вас есть список JSONValue? какие именно значения в нем вам не известно? какие ключи вам не известны? как определить, что значение надо вывести?

Comment: JSONValue это класс с различными конструкторами(6 различных которые принимают на вход: boolean, String, int, double, JSONArray, JSONObject). В свою очередь конструктор класса JSONObject принимает на вход JSONObjectElement(пару ключ:значение). Конструктор класса JSONObjectElement принимает на вход String как ключ и JSONValue как значение. И когда я читаю JSON файл в String я пытаюсь разбить его на объекты, о которых рассказал выше, тем самым подразделяя их.

Comment: что значит последний объект?  как определить, что значение надо вывести?

Comment: Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю вам создать метод, который будет проверять добрались ли вы до конечного значения. Что-то типо этого:

```
public boolean isEnd() {
    if (value instanceof String)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Вместо стринг можете подставить свой конечный тип, если он есть, либо проверять "не принадлежность" к типам JSONValue и JSONObject.

Потом в цикле написать так

```
for (int index = 0; index < parserJson.size(); index++) {
        JSONValue value = parserJson.get(index).getValues();
        while(!value.isEnd()){
           value = value.getValues();
        }
        System.out.println(parserJson.get(index).getValues());
    }
```

Comment: как вы собрались добавить метод в чужой класс? у вас бесконечный цикл.

Comment: да согласен, кривой ответ получился. Сейчас ещё раз перечитал вопрос, подумал и получается, что можно выстроить огромную иерархию объектов, у каждого из которых будут разные методы для получения значения (где-то getValue, где-то просто get, где-то нужен ключ...). Это почти не реально, либо я слишком мало знаю =)

Comment: про это и речь - ТС не сформулировал задачу